# Preciso de duas data, o metodo onDateSet executa e coloca a dataselecionada nos dois Textview

Tags: android, datepicker

```
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month , int dayOfMonth) {
        //função execultada apos a escolha da data
        dataSelecionada = String.format("%02d/%02d/%d", dayOfMonth, ++month, year);
        data.setText(dataSelecionada);
        data2.setText(dataSelecionada);
    }

    public DatePickerFragment(TextView data, TextView data2){
       this.data = data ;
       this.data2 = data2;
    }

}

public void AbrirCalendario() {
    // abrir calendario
    DialogFragment calendario = new DatePickerFragment(data, data2);
    // suporte fragment, string de indentificação do fragment
    calendario.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datepicker");
}
```

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida

Comment: Seja um pouco mais específico quanto a sua dúvida.

Comment: Preciso de uma data de entrada e uma de saida, para aluguel de quartos, porém a formatação dataselecionada, pega a mesma data do Datepicker e coloca nas duas TextView, nao sei outra forma de usar

Comment: A tag `android-studio` só deve ser usada para perguntas relacionadas com a IDE.

Comment: Não dá pra te ajudar sem saber de onde estão vindo data e data2 .